# Set Tab size with Apache-POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'd like to set the tab size via Apache-POI in a Word document.

I have a header, which should take two fiels in it's header line like this:

```
|    filed1                  ->                   field2    |
```

The vertical lines represent the edges of the page.
I want the tab in between both fields as big, so that the first field is left justified to the page and the right field is right justified to the page.

It's pretty easy to be done with Word itself, but I only found out how to add a tab with POI, but not on how to set the width of the tab.

I tried to investigate the Word files with Apaches tika tool, but did not see, where the tab size is buried in the file.

Any help appreciated,
Maik

Comment: I think you could create 2 columns, one justified to the left, one justified to the right

Comment: Yes, that idea came to me, too, since it is pretty easy to add a table with POI. But I'm just curious, if it is possible to implement different tab constraints within one Word file, which is a very common thing to do, when you work with a document in Word itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab stops are settings in paragraphs of Word. And although using tab stops is  a very common thing to do and also a very old procedure in word processing, it is not possible without using the low level underlying ooxml-schema objects of `apache poi`.

Example:

Note : measurement unit for tab stop pos is twips (twentieth of an inch point).

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTabStop;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordHeaderWithTabStops {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body...");

  // create header
  XWPFHeader header = doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);

  // header's first paragraph
  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  // create tab stops
  int twipsPerInch = 1440; //measurement unit for tab stop pos is twips (twentieth of an inch point)

  CTTabStop tabStop = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewTabs().addNewTab();
  tabStop.setVal(STTabJc.CENTER);
  tabStop.setPos(BigInteger.valueOf(3 * twipsPerInch));

  tabStop = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getTabs().addNewTab();
  tabStop.setVal(STTabJc.RIGHT);
  tabStop.setPos(BigInteger.valueOf(6 * twipsPerInch));

  // first run in header's first paragraph, to be for first text box
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("Left");
  // add tab to run
  run.addTab();

  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("Center");
  // add tab to run
  run.addTab();

  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("Right");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderWithTabStops.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  doc.close();
  out.close();


 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Axel, I'm quite impressed on how you answer my questions with detailed explanations and of course, with exactly the result I was looking for. Thank you very much for this! I did think to myself, that it must have been somewhere low level, but I do lack very much experience on knowing, how all this low level stuff is organized. Your answers give very much insight view of this!